# C++: How to trigger a compiler error when function return value is unused?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, return-value

Let's say I have a normalize function defined as:

```
Vec3f Vec3f::getNormalized() const {
   return (*this)/this->length();
}
```

Is it somehow possible to create a compile-time error if this function is used without something storing it's return value? ;

```
v.getNormalized(); // which most definitely is a typo
```

..instead of..

```
v = v.getNormalized();
```

Comment: If the method is declared `const` and nothing is storing the return value, I would think that problem would be optimized away so you wouldn't have to worry. But good question anyway.

Comment: From an optimization point of view, I don't think this is a problem, regardless of if the function is declared const or not.

Comment: Is it ok, if you can check it runtime ?

Comment: I don't know if it was just for the example, but if not, can you avoid "v = v.blah()" or "v = blah(v)" and if possible use different variables for each stage of the calculation, making it much more obvious to you when you leave an assignment out, even if it doesn't have the compiler checking? "Vec3f v_init = foo(); v_norm = v.GetNormalised(); Vec3f v_ans = v_norm * v_other; etc;"

Comment: Or, not really what you want, but use a binary function or operator, so "v.assignNormalisedTo(v)".

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In GCC, use `-Wunused-result` to trigger the warning when a function's return value is ignored. And if you want an error instead of warning, use `-Werror` to convert all warnings into errors. For more information see **[GCC Warning Options](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html)**.

There does not seem to be an equivalent warning for the Visual C++ compiler. (If I am wrong, please edit this reply with the Visual C++ information.)

Answer (score 6):

There's no way to know whether or not the return value was taken. The only way to guarantee that one was passed in is to pass in the return value by reference.

Comment: In other words, `void Vec3f::getNormalized(Vec3f& result)` However be careful about what happens if you call `v.getNormalised(v)`

Comment: Peter Hull; in that case, i'd make the function static.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this is possible at compile-time, except by using compiler flags as [@Ashwin noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5803623/compile-time-error-when-nobody-receives-the-return-value-from-a-function-in-c/5803942#5803942).

However, if it is ok to generate an error at runtime, you could perhaps use some tricks, like using a proxy class:

```
template <typename T>
struct Return
{
    Return(const T & value) 
      : value_(value), used_(false) 
    {}

    Return(const Return & other) 
      : value_(other.value_), used_(false) 
    { 
        other.used_ = true; 
    }


    Return & operator=(const Return & other)
    {
        other.used_ = true;
        value_ = other.value;
        return *this;
    }

    operator T() const 
    { 
        used_ = true; 
        return value_;
    }

    ~Return() // generates an error if the value hasn't been used
    { 
        assert(used_); 
    }

  private:

    T value_;
    mutable bool used_;
};

Return<int> foo()
{
    return 42;
}

int main()
{
    int i = foo();                   // ok
    std::cout << foo() << std::endl; // ok

    foo();                           // assertion failed
}
```

You just need to change the return type of your function so that it returns a `Return<Vec3f>` and you should obtain an error if the result of the function is unused. However, I'm not sure I would recommend that, since it makes the code less clear and can probably be misused as well. As long as your function is well-documented, you should have confidence in your users :)!

Comment: I was thinking about something like that. I wouldn't use it in real code, but it's a nice academic solution.

Answer (score 2):

With clang, you can selectively transform a given warning into an error (rather than all).

This is achieved with the `-Werror=foo` where `foo` is the name of the warning. Here I think that `-Werror=unused-expr` is what you'd need.